Addressing endogeneity issue in Cox model
I’m working with panel data where the variables are group level indicators of performance. To put simply, the predictor is a group-level aggregated quantity (e.g., average reputation of members) which is time varying over several periods (the predicted variable being group performance). I have reason to believe that the predictor is not strictly exogenous since at times the group is constituted with an aim to make it perform well. However, a “part” of the predictor is exogeneous – it happens when a group member suddenly exits the group in one of the periods (death or some reason, which is strictly exogenous). So, for identification, I am thinking of creating two components of the predictor in my dataset: the first is the group level (reputation) measure assuming no exogenous shock – i.e., the group member has not left the group), and the second component would be the delta(predictor) ONLY there is an exogenous shock (death or some other reason) – this delta(predictor) would be a negative quantity if the exiting group member has an above-average reputation, and would be a positive quantity if the exiting group member has a below-average reputation. In any case, the second component would be the exogenous component of the predictor – and its coefficient should be ideally significant when testing for the proposed hypothesis. Now having said this, to slightly complicate the matters, I am using Cox regression (predicted is a duration variable) with time-varying covariates, BUT that is beside the point since the essential question I have from you all is whether my strategy makes sense.

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.
